# Executable file on OS

Tags: file, executable

I thought once over how the operating system, and I have come to do if you ever make your own system. Quite simply own system and its own API, kernel, executable format, and etc.

But this is the issue when you create a custom executable format and API.

I want to ask how to be able to export (e.g. compiler) GCC in my system. You could do this? despite the fact that I have a custom executable format and API?

(in the sense that my system does not have any executable format an extensive system like Linux, Windows, Mac OS X) But I can create a custom executable format.

I have 15 years but I'd like to know more.

Comment: I’m having some trouble deciphering what you’re asking. Are you asking how to modify GCC to produce a file with a custom format?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what the question is here, but I *think* OP is asking how you would go about porting a compiler (such as GCC) to a new operating system, since it has to work with a new executable format, new OS API, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this will be an easy task.You can compile gcc program to assembly using `-fverbose-asm` flag, as this will be easiest option, you cannot define your own executable meta data that would be compiled by GCC until you are a bigshot.

So assembly seems to be good option. Next you will have to write an interpreter that would process your code to your system calls,processor calls & native functions. Surely you will have to manage memory, and access to system calls.

It seems too be easy but in reality it is not.Point me if i am wrong somewhere.